# UIWebView and scroller indicators

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.

I have a problem with scroller indicator. When I load a simle web form into a UIWebView, the scroller indicator appear on the right side of the screen. It's right, but when I try to edit some field on the form, scroller indicator move at center of the WebView, as you can see on the picture. Please, help me to solve this issue.

[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/7351/img0058w.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/7351/img0058w.png)

**Update:**

I'll try to add some details here.

I created an empty View-based project.

In the plist file I add a line:

```
Initial interface orientation = Landscape (right home button)
```

After that I open an empty View in Interface Builer and add a UIWebView.

Then in ViewController I created an Outlet for it.

In the -vievDidLoaded function I wrote next code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my_url"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

Here is the html code of loaded page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html>
 <head>
  <link href="/mobileproduct/css/webform/default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
<body>
  <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/mobileproduct/webform/buildwebform" method="post" class="webform"><dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="token-label">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd id="token-element">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="1700ec7d06a1a0521670d7df8ccd9571" id="token" /></dd>
<dt id="authDataGroup-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="authDataGroup-element"><fieldset id="fieldset-authDataGroup"><legend>Personal info</legend>
<dl>
<dt id="name-label"><label for="name" class="required">Name:</label></dt>
<dd id="name-element">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="NameHh" maxlength="30" /></dd>
<dt id="nick-label"><label for="nick" class="required">Nick:</label></dt>
<dd id="nick-element">
<input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" value="nicker" maxlength="30" /></dd>
<dt id="email-label"><label for="email" class="required">E-mail:</label></dt>
<dd id="email-element">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="mozart@gmail.com" maxlength="80" /></dd></dl></fieldset></dd>
<dt id="dataGroup-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="dataGroup-element"><fieldset id="fieldset-dataGroup"><legend>Additional info</legend>
<dl>
<dt id="ref_custom_5-label"><label for="ref_custom_5" class="optional">Question 1</label></dt>
<dd id="ref_custom_5-element">
<input type="text" name="ref_custom_5" id="ref_custom_5" value="Na" /></dd>
<dt id="ref_custom_6-label"><label for="ref_custom_6" class="optional">Question 2</label></dt>
<dd id="ref_custom_6-element">
<input type="text" name="ref_custom_6" id="ref_custom_6" value="qq" /></dd>
<dt id="ref_select_2-label"><label for="ref_select_2" class="optional">Select Gender</label></dt>
<dd id="ref_select_2-element">
<select name="ref_select_2" id="ref_select_2">
    <option value="" label="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1" label="male">male</option>
    <option value="2" label="female" selected="selected">female</option>
</select></dd></dl></fieldset></dd>
<dt id="buttonsGroup-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="buttonsGroup-element"><fieldset id="fieldset-buttonsGroup"><dl>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />

<input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Restore" /></dl></fieldset></dd></dl></form></body>
</html>
```

If I dont edit any of the field on the form, the scroll indicator looks normal. But after input (or, if you want, after showing/hiding virtual keyboard) the scroll indicator moves to the wrong position.

Stupid problem, but I really dont know how to solve it.

Comment: How do you create the WebView? Do you set it's frame explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that before. Try running your html through a [syntax checker](http://validator.w3.org/) for starters. But without seeing obj-c and html source code, there's not much to work with.